# My text is in YAML(.yml) file and I want to display some text in bold

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, yaml

My text is in YAML(.yml) file and I want to display some text in bold but if I add  tag then it is displayed as it is instead of making the text bold.

e.g

vaccum:
-    company: Shark 
      power: 100W 
      instructions: Power up and select the < b>operation speed and type< /b>.

But in the HTML page it is displayed as "Power up and select the < b>operation speed and type< /b>." instead of "Power up and select the **operation speed and type**."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML is a data format, not a markup language. If your application is not interpreting the content of this field as HTML, you will need to change it to make this happen.